# Disabled input text color on iOS

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari, webkit

The simple HTML below displays differently in Firefox and WebKit-based browsers (I checked in Safari, Chrome and iPhone).

In Firefox both border and text have the same color (`#880000`), but in Safari the text gets a bit lighter (as if it had some transparency applied to it).

Can I somehow fix this (remove this transparency in Safari)?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        input:disabled{
            border:solid 1px #880000;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            color:#880000;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" value="disabled input box" disabled="disabled"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also noticed this, for me this is a bug, since when you put background-color:white of the input it will show the color again correctly. Also opacity has little effect. Althought the -webkit-text-fill-color:#880000 will work

Comment: iOS is the new IE

Answer (score 311, accepted):

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: #880000;
opacity: 1; /* required on iOS */
```

Comment: I wanted my disabled input box to look like a normal one.  This is the only thing that would work in Safari Mobile.       -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    background: white;

Comment: It is also needed on Android stock browser

Comment: Opacity isn't needed in current builds of Safari, as of Summer 2016.

Comment: Saved my day! Yet it also affects the coloring of the `placeholder` text color of the `input` element. In case you'll need a fix for it too, look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Answer (score 50):

Phone and Tablet webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) and desktop IE have a number of default changes to disabled form elements that you'll need to override if you want to style disabled inputs.

```
-webkit-text-fill-color:#880000; /* Override iOS / Android font color change */
-webkit-opacity:1; /* Override iOS opacity change affecting text & background color */
color:#880000; /* Override IE font color change */
```

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATED 2021:**

Combining ideas from this page into a "set and forget" reset that makes all disabled text the same as normal text.

```
input:disabled, textarea:disabled, input:disabled::placeholder, textarea:disabled::placeholder {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: currentcolor; /* 1. sets text fill to current `color` for safari */
  opacity: 1; /* 2. correct opacity on iOS */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as a "set and forget" solution. `currentColor` doesn't seem to behave as expected when used with `-webkit-text-fill-color`: https://jsfiddle.net/y1sgena2/2/

Comment: @esten I've reviewed this and it still seems to work in the latest Safari/iOS (2021)

Comment: the fiddle I posted works? Not working for me in safari Version 14.1.1 - not sure if thats the latest version

Comment: @esten your fiddle demonstrates that something isn't working, I can see that too and I'm not sure why - maybe you're trying to have a custom disabled color, which the "set and forget" reset solution i posted doesn't do of course. Here's a working fiddle with my solution (tested in iOS14.2) https://jsfiddle.net/crgm4bz9/1/

Comment: @paulcol. Your fiddle currentColor isn't working when I change color to green.

Answer (score 6):

it's an interesting question and I've tried plenty of overrides to see if I can get it going, but nothing's working.  Modern browsers actually use their own style sheets to tell elements how to display, so maybe if you can sniff out Chrome's stylesheet you can see what styles they're forcing on to it. I'll be very interested in the result and if you don't have one I'll spend a little time myself looking for it later when I have some time to waste.

FYI,

```
opacity: 1!important;
```

doesn't override it, so I'm not sure it's opacity.

Comment: thanks!  
I couldn't find an explanation (nothing like that in Chrome's user agent style sheet - only "background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228)" for disabled inputs) and I'm using a workaround, but still curious what's going on ...

Comment: Steve, thank you for the effort, but I suggest in the future you post this as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could change color to `#440000` just for Safari, but IMHO the best solution would be **not to** change looks of button *at all*. This way, in every browser on every platform, it will look just like users expect it to.

Answer (score 6):

for @ryan

I wanted my disabled input box to look like a normal one. This is the only thing that would work in Safari Mobile.

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-webkit-opacity: 1;
background: white;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the readonly attribute instead of the disabled attribute, but then you will need to add a class because there isn't a pseudo-class input:readonly.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
button.readonly{
    border:solid 1px #880000;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#880000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <button type="button" readonly="readonly" class="readonly">disabled input box</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Beware that a disabled input and readonly input aren't the same.
A readonly input can have focus, and will send values on submit. Look at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12)

Comment: thanks man  
yep, this was my first idea too, but it doesn't work for me because of focus: on iPhone the keyboard pops up when a user taps a readonly element, and this is confusing  
I've found my workaround, and my question is rather 'theoretical' - why this behaviour?

Comment: An interesting workaround: the focus issue also poses usability problems, in particular for people using screen readers. In most cases, you just wouldn't want users to be able to tab to readonly/disabled fields in a form.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fix the problem for all the disabled inputs, you can define `-webkit-text-fill-color` to `currentcolor`, so the `color` property of the input will be used.

```css
input[disabled] {
   -webkit-text-fill-color: currentcolor;
}
```

See that fiddle on Safari
https://jsfiddle.net/u549yk87/3/

Answer (score 2):

This question is very old but I thought that I would post an updated webkit solution.
Just use the following CSS:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #880000;
}
```

Comment: and for Firefox, use input:-moz-placeholder

Comment: eh.. this is for the placeholder attribute, I don't think that has an affect on disabled fields. @Kemo's answer below (`-webkit-text-fill-color`) does work though

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a button instead of an input?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    button:disabled{
        border:solid 1px #880000;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        color:#880000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <button type="button" disabled="disabled">disabled input box</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not really... in my real application those textboxes are usually enabled and used for input, and only under certain conditions they get disabled with JavaScript
I can figure out a workaround (like, replace <input/> with a styled <div></div> instead of setting 'disabled') - but it really feels wrong

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

```css
.default:disabled {
  background-color: var(--white-200);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: var(--black-transparent-300);
}
    
.default::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-text-fill-color:  var(--color-placeholder);
  color: var(--color-placeholder) !important;
}
```