# How to change disabled option text color in the pull down list?

Tags: html, css

How can I change the font color of a disabled `option` in a `select` menu? (Not the select itself, just its options in the pull down menu)
I want to do this because in chrome/safari there is almost no difference between disabled/enabled options (See first picture). In IE the difference is somehow obvious. In Firefox it quite obvious.

Below approach only works in FF. How can I do this in a cross-browser manner? 
https://jsfiddle.net/6wazms1a/3/

HTML:

```
<select>
    <!-- I want to change text color of 'disabled' in the pull down list. 
Reason: Make non-disabled options more prominent (like in IE and Firefox) -->
    <option disabled>disabled</option> 
    <option selected>enabled selected</option>
    <option>other enabled</option>   
    <option>another enabled</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
option:disabled,
option[disabled],
option[disabled="disabled"] { color: #ccc; }
```

So far my results:

#### Chrome/Safari

Bad. There is almost no difference between enabled/disabled options. I can hardly tell what is enabled and what is not.

[image]
[image]

### Firefox and IE (OK)

Good. Very easy to spot disabled options

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

see whether this works :
-webkit-text-fill-color:blue;

source:
[Disabled input text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262158/disabled-input-text-color?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To set via Jquery all options

```
$("option:disabled").css("color","gray");
```

or even more detailed via css

```
option:disabled {
color: gray;
text-align: right;
font-style: italic;
font-size: smaller;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(selectObject)
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .css({
        "color":"red",
        "background-color":"white",
        "border-style":"solid"
    });
```

Comment: I believe this is for the select. not its options

Comment: this disables the select